# Векторный город с помощью элементов

Tags: html, css

Сделал векторную картинку с помощью элементов html. Но почему то, когда я меняю высоту окна, она странно реагирует и всё сжимается, хотя должно оставаться таким же.

```css
body {background-color: rgba(51, 170, 255, 1)}
.ground {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vh;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10vh;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 14vh;
}
.home-0 {left: 7vw;}
.home-1 {left: 22vw;}
.home-2 {left: 39vw;}
.home-3 {left: 55vw;}
.home-4 {left: 71vw;}

.home-window {
  background-color: white;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vh;
  margin: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="home home-0">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-1">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-2">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-3">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-4">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="ground"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы размеры высоты считаете от размера высоты страницы, а ширину от ширины. Что бы изображение сохраняло целостность, нужно везде указывать от высоты страницы или от ширины:

```css
body {background-color: rgba(51, 170, 255, 1)}
.ground {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 10vw;
  background-color: #eee;
}
.home {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10vw;
  background-color: #e0e0e0;
  padding: 1vw;
  width: 10vw;
  height: 14vw;
}
.home-0 {left: 7vw;}
.home-1 {left: 22vw;}
.home-2 {left: 39vw;}
.home-3 {left: 55vw;}
.home-4 {left: 71vw;}

.home-window {
  background-color: white;
  width: 3vw;
  height: 3vw;
  margin: 1vw;
}
```

```html
<div class="home home-0">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-1">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-2">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-3">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="home home-4">
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
  <div class="home-window"></div>
</div>
<div class="ground"></div>
```

Comment: О, не допёр сразу. Спасибо :)

Comment: @AnatShir, если вам помог мой ответ, отметьте его как правильный.

Comment: а как отметить:

Comment: @AnatShir, там возле ответа галочка такая :)

Comment: Через семь минут можно только отметить. Скажите, а как сделать сонце, которое крутилось бы еще?

Comment: @AnatShir, создаёте так же объект и с помощью анимации создаёте вращение

Comment: Можете показать как?

Comment: @AnatShir, почитайте статью https://html5book.ru/css3-animation/

Comment: Спасибо :) Можно потом ещё к вам обращаться?

Comment: @AnatShir, на сайте есть люди и поумнее меня в этом деле. Пишите вопросы и вам на них ответят.

Comment: Ну ладно, всё равно спасибо